# Ensuring div is even size and text shrinks to fit without needing overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css

This is a simple used automobile sales platform for a dealer who doesn't want a lot of interactivity, just a listing of the vehicles and prices in a visual manner similar to a print magazine (click on Run Code Snippet and View Full page to see it as it looks currently):

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header, footer {
background-color: #7690AC;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.content {
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.grid {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  }
.grid > article {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  min-height: 25em;
  top: -10px;
  }
.grid > article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.text {
font-size: 1em;
transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1);
margin-left: 25px;
width: 270px;
}
.text {
  padding: 0 10px 20px;
}
.text > button {
  background: gray;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  }
h3.price {
text-align: center;
}

.cards {
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 4rem;
}

p.address, p.phoneno {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 900;
line-height: 12px;
}

&phone;:before {
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>YOURMOTORHOMES</h1>
<h2>Axtley Road, Penderton XX1 1XA</h2>
<h2>01634 00000</h2>
</header>
<div class="content">
<p>Welcome to YourMotorhomes!</p>
</div>
<main class="grid">
  <article>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PApYyjj.jpg" alt="Elddis Autoquest">
    <div class="text">
      <p><b>2020 70 ELDDIS AUTOQUEST 194 2.2 HDi 140 LOW PROFILE MOTORHOME PEUGEOT BOXER CHASSIS</b>
      4 berth, end washroom, white, 100 litre fresh water, 70 litre waste water, 3 ring hob, OG cooker, 155 litre fridge, 600 miles, almost as new, <b class="price">£44895</b></p>
    </div>
  </article>
      <article>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h7Cujxy.jpg" alt="Dethleffs Esprit"><em>Image for illustration purposes only</em>
    <div class="text">
      <p><b>2014 64 DETHLEFFS i6810 ESPRIT 2.3 MULTIJET 130 A-CLASS FIAT DUCATO MOTORHOME</b>
      4 berth, 4 belted seats A-class motorhome finished in Diamodn White, fixed single bed layout, 3 ring cooker, fully loaded spec, 28,000 miles <b class="price">£62115</b></p>
    </div>
  </article>  
    <article>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TfuaqVa.jpg" alt="Burstner Aviano">
    <div class="text">
      <p><b>2009 59 BURSTNER AVIANO i725 3.0 MULTIJET 180 FIAT TD</b>
      4 berth, gold, island bed layout, 3 ring hob, 150 litre fridge, 7.45m length, 2.30m width <b class="price">£44995</b></p>
    </div>
  </article>      
  <article>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oUWFVub.jpg" alt="Burstner Nexxo">
    <div class="text">
      <p><b>2009 58 BURSTNER NEXXO FAMILY A645 2.2 TDCi</b>
      6 berth, 6 belted seats, end bedroom, blue, Layout - Over Cab Double, Centre Dinette Double, Rear Bunk beds, 2 Owners from New, Good Service History, Cab Air Conditioning, Gaslow Refillable LPG System, Truma Blown Air Combination Boiler, HPI Clear, Roof Rails, Large Garage - if not using bottom bunk, Awning,MOT 17/12/2021, 11 Service Stamps in the book, Last Damp check 01/21, GVW 3500kg, Length 6.56m, Width 2.30m, Height 3.0m, only 20,747 miles, registered 30/01/2009, MoT due in Oct' 21. DUE THIS WEEK. A GREAT EXAMPLE OF THIS BURSTNER MOTORHOME, MUST BE SEEN NOW, YOU WILL NOT FIND BETTER 
      <b class="price">£35000</b></p>
    </div>
  </article>

</main>
<footer>
content
</footer>
```

Functionally, it works, but I want to try and achieve three things; the  within grid being all the same size, and also the images being the same size within the article (I've got it at max-width:100%) so it's not creating uneven sizes (if you view the design at full screen) and preventing text overflow by auto-resizing the font if there's a lot of text without needing a scrollbar or overflow: hidden; in the CSS.

I would be grateful if anyone can help, as this template's working, not quite production-ready, but it's getting there slowly.

Comment: What do you want the fixed height of each to be? Also, I think you’ll need some JavaScript for the font size decreasing, is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this - 
1. Remove transform property form .text class and 
2. Remove align-items from .grid class. 

    .text {
        font-size: 1em;
        /* transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1); */ // Comment it. 
        margin-left: 25px;
        width: 270px;
    }
    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 20px;
        /* align-items: center; */ //Comment it. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The given code arranges the articles in a grid which adjusts to the viewport width OK but these things are required:

1. The height of each article should be the same
2. The height of each image should be the same
3. The text should have font-size adjusted so that it always fits within the article size

Taking each requirement in turn:

1. Set the height of article to something. It depends on what you think would be sensible bearing in mind the maximum amount of text a van may require - to ensure its text will still be readable. The snippet below sets it at 30em (based on the code in the question having a minimum height of 25em)
2. Although we want the height of each img to be the same, say a % of the article height, we need to ensure that the whole of the img is always viewable, without distortion or cropping. This snippet changes the HTML so that the img element becomes a div with fixed dimensions and the image is used as a background, centered both horizontally and vertically and with size contain. (see below for alternative).
3. Altering the font size I think requires Javascript. This snippet looks at the height of the text div and if it's too tall alters the font size until it fits. You may want to put a different limit on it so that it is always readable, even if that means occasionally the user having to scroll.

```js
const articles = document.querySelectorAll('.grid > article');
    articles.forEach(article => {
      const articleH = article.offsetHeight;
      let h = article.querySelector('.text').offsetHeight;
      var fontSize = 0.9;
      while (h > articleH/2) {//NOTE assumes the img is 50% alter if it is something else
        article.querySelector('.text').style.fontSize = fontSize + 'em';
        h = article.querySelector('.text').offsetHeight;
        if (fontSize <= 0.2) break;
        fontSize = fontSize - 0.05;
      }
    });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100vw;
    }

    header, footer {
    background-color: #7690AC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .content {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .grid {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .grid { 
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
      grid-gap: 20px;
      align-items: center;
      }
    .grid > article {
      border: 1px solid #333;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      /* min-height: 25em; */
      height: 30em; /* ADDED */
      top: -10px;
      }
    .grid > article .img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .text {
    font-size: 1em;
    /*transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1);*/
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 270px;
    }
    .text {
      padding: 0 10px 20px;
    }
    .text > button {
      background: gray;
      border: 0;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      }
    h3.price {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    border-collapse: collapse;
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 1rem;
    }

    .card {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
      color: white;
      padding: 1rem;
      height: 4rem;
    }

    p.address, p.phoneno {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 12px;
    }

    &phone;:before {
    font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>YOURMOTORHOMES</h1>
    <h2>Axtley Road, Penderton XX1 1XA</h2>
    <h2>01634 00000</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
    <p>Welcome to YourMotorhomes!</p>
    </div>
    <main class="grid">
      <article>
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/PApYyjj.jpg)" alt="Elddis Autoquest"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <p><b>2020 70 ELDDIS AUTOQUEST 194 2.2 HDi 140 LOW PROFILE MOTORHOME PEUGEOT BOXER CHASSIS</b>
          4 berth, end washroom, white, 100 litre fresh water, 70 litre waste water, 3 ring hob, OG cooker, 155 litre fridge, 600 miles, almost as new, <b class="price">£44895</b></p>
        </div>
      </article>
          <article>
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url( https://i.imgur.com/h7Cujxy.jpg" alt="Dethleffs Esprit)"></div><em>Image for illustration purposes only</em>
        <div class="text">
          <p><b>2014 64 DETHLEFFS i6810 ESPRIT 2.3 MULTIJET 130 A-CLASS FIAT DUCATO MOTORHOME</b>
          4 berth, 4 belted seats A-class motorhome finished in Diamodn White, fixed single bed layout, 3 ring cooker, fully loaded spec, 28,000 miles <b class="price">£62115</b></p>
        </div>
      </article>  
        <article>
       <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/TfuaqVa.jpg)" alt="Burstner Aviano"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <p><b>2009 59 BURSTNER AVIANO i725 3.0 MULTIJET 180 FIAT TD</b>
          4 berth, gold, island bed layout, 3 ring hob, 150 litre fridge, 7.45m length, 2.30m width <b class="price">£44995</b></p>
        </div>
      </article>      
      <article>
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/oUWFVub.jpg);" alt="Burstner Nexxo"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <p><b>2009 58 BURSTNER NEXXO FAMILY A645 2.2 TDCi</b>
          6 berth, 6 belted seats, end bedroom, blue, Layout - Over Cab Double, Centre Dinette Double, Rear Bunk beds, 2 Owners from New, Good Service History, Cab Air Conditioning, Gaslow Refillable LPG System, Truma Blown Air Combination Boiler, HPI Clear, Roof Rails, Large Garage - if not using bottom bunk, Awning,MOT 17/12/2021, 11 Service Stamps in the book, Last Damp check 01/21, GVW 3500kg, Length 6.56m, Width 2.30m, Height 3.0m, only 20,747 miles, registered 30/01/2009, MoT due in Oct' 21. DUE THIS WEEK. A GREAT EXAMPLE OF THIS BURSTNER MOTORHOME, MUST BE SEEN NOW, YOU WILL NOT FIND BETTER 
          <b class="price">£35000</b></p>
        </div>
      </article>

    </main>
    <footer>
    content
    </footer>
```

An alternative to contain on the background size could be cover - if you were absolutely sure that the motor was central in each image and the aspect ratio such that it would fit OK. This runs a risk that not all the van will show though, but it gives a more consistent solid look to the top part of the article.